# Graph in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, graph

How to design this type of graph in Microsoft excel that can be seen in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axq2J.png). I want to design a graph and compare the result of benchmark 1 with the result of benchmark 2 and 3 as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is Clustered Column Chart with Multi-Level Axis Label.

See the image for data table sample.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuIzM.png)

hi Rajesh, thanks for the response but I am finding some problems. I have tried your way but certainly, I am committing some mistake. kindly correct me. thanks.